# Mavericks HDD swapped while in sleep mode is now unreadable

Tags: sleep-wake

Recently I was attempting to upgrade from mavericks to Yosemite and was having difficulty getting Yosemite to run.  I left the machine running rather than shutting down and it went into sleep mode. 
Several hours later I took out the Yosemite disk and replaced it with the one on which Mavericks was installed and hit the start button only to have the computer come to life immediately and started writing to the Mavericks HDD.  Needless to say I now have a corrupted Mavericks installation with about 500 gigabytes of images and video recordings which I cannot access.

Is there any way to recover files off this disk or should I just wipe it cut my losses.

Comment: Why can't you access them, are they corrupted too?  Have you tried attaching that disk in an external enclosure to a working OS X to see if the files can be accessed?

Comment: Have tried hooking it up as an external hard drive to Mavericks but does not show except in disk utility and have tried the tools in that program to no effect.
Am currently giving Testdisk a try and will see what happens. Most other programs I have tried as a trials do not see the disk. If Testdisk is too difficult will wipe and start again. Thanks to those who have commented.

Answer (score 1):

Oh man - that's a bad situation. All is certainly not lost.

I would start by calling one or two data recovery services to get a quote from them. Once you have that, consider you could pay $99 for software that would look over the drive and offer to recover files.

With those estimates, you can decide if your time and photos are worth further efforts to salvage or if you just write them off and erase the drive to start over.